# fixing parenthesis in regex for linkify php function?

Tags: php, regex, linkify

I've implemented "linkify" on our OSticket system and it seems to be working wonderfully, except for one noted flaw that I didn't notice in the documentiation http://jmrware.com/articles/2010/linkifyurl/linkify.php.  When the link is followed by a ), it INCLUDES that ) in the link.  GRRR

So I was wondering if there are any super regex guys out there that might be able to debug seeing as how linkify hasn't been updated in a couple years now...

Here is the regex if needed:

```
 $url_pattern = '/# Rev:20100913_0900 github.com\/jmrware\/LinkifyURL
    # Match http & ftp URL that is not already linkified.
      # Alternative 1: URL delimited by (parentheses).
      (\()                     # $1  "(" start delimiter.
      ((?:ht|f)tps?:\/\/[a-z0-9\-._~!$&\'()*+,;=:\/?#[\]@%]+)  # $2: URL.
      (\))                     # $3: ")" end delimiter.
    | # Alternative 2: URL delimited by [square brackets].
      (\[)                     # $4: "[" start delimiter.
      ((?:ht|f)tps?:\/\/[a-z0-9\-._~!$&\'()*+,;=:\/?#[\]@%]+)  # $5: URL.
      (\])                     # $6: "]" end delimiter.
    | # Alternative 3: URL delimited by {curly braces}.
      (\{)                     # $7: "{" start delimiter.
      ((?:ht|f)tps?:\/\/[a-z0-9\-._~!$&\'()*+,;=:\/?#[\]@%]+)  # $8: URL.
      (\})                     # $9: "}" end delimiter.
    | # Alternative 4: URL delimited by <angle brackets>.
      (<|&(?:lt|\#60|\#x3c);)  # $10: "<" start delimiter (or HTML entity).
      ((?:ht|f)tps?:\/\/[a-z0-9\-._~!$&\'()*+,;=:\/?#[\]@%]+)  # $11: URL.
      (>|&(?:gt|\#62|\#x3e);)  # $12: ">" end delimiter (or HTML entity).
    | # Alternative 5: URL not delimited by (), [], {} or <>.
      (                        # $13: Prefix proving URL not already linked.
        (?: ^                  # Can be a beginning of line or string, or
        | [^=\s\'"\]]          # a non-"=", non-quote, non-"]", followed by
        ) \s*[\'"]?            # optional whitespace and optional quote;
      | [^=\s]\s+              # or... a non-equals sign followed by whitespace.
      )                        # End $13. Non-prelinkified-proof prefix.
      ( \b                     # $14: Other non-delimited URL.
        (?:ht|f)tps?:\/\/      # Required literal http, https, ftp or ftps prefix.
        [a-z0-9\-._~!$\'()*+,;=:\/?#[\]@%]+ # All URI chars except "&" (normal*).
        (?:                    # Either on a "&" or at the end of URI.
          (?!                  # Allow a "&" char only if not start of an...
            &(?:gt|\#0*62|\#x0*3e);                  # HTML ">" entity, or
          | &(?:amp|apos|quot|\#0*3[49]|\#x0*2[27]); # a [&\'"] entity if
            [.!&\',:?;]?        # followed by optional punctuation then
            (?:[^a-z0-9\-._~!$&\'()*+,;=:\/?#[\]@%]|$)  # a non-URI char or EOS.
          ) &                  # If neg-assertion true, match "&" (special).
          [a-z0-9\-._~!$\'()*+,;=:\/?#[\]@%]* # More non-& URI chars (normal*).
        )*                     # Unroll-the-loop (special normal*)*.
        [a-z0-9\-_~$()*+=\/#[\]@%]  # Last char can\'t be [.!&\',;:?]
      )                        # End $14. Other non-delimited URL.
    /imx';
```

I started to play around with it, but it proves to be a bit over my head.  I am also up for OTHER alternative suggestions instead of linkify as well?

If you note the second to last line:  `# Last char can\'t be [.!&\',;:?]` Basically, it'd be nice to add a ) in there.... ?

Comment: A valid URL link may have parentheses at the end (in the path, query or fragment). If you wish to exclude it, (if it is not part of a balanced pair), then you will need to apply more logic.

Answer (score 0):

If you just want to match substrings that look like HTTP/FTP URLs, but don't end with punctuation etc, you could use something simple like:

```
\b(?:ht|f)tps?://[^\s<>"']+(?![][()<>{}.,!?:;"'])
```